# Use npm to copy front-end modules to a top-level directory

Tags: node.js, build, npm, workflow

I've converted to npm for my build system: no gulp etc. Also no webpack, rollup etc, it's an es6 system based on modules & no bundling. Sure is simple!

Obviously I don't want to drag around a node_modules hierarchy for my run-time, front end modules. And don't want to `import foo from './node_modules/god/awful/path.js'`. So I'd like to have a top level directory for the run-time, front-end dependencies.

So how do I copy my "dependencies", not "devDependencies", to a top level directory for deployment?

I've got a run script that can do it but it's pretty messy and the location of the package under node_modules is not always obvious. Maybe there's a package for doing this automatically? Or a nifty npm trick of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm starting to need this even more than before so thought I'd nag and be clearer about what I seem to be forced to do.

First of all, I use no workflow task managers, just npm run scripts in package.json.

My dependencies (npm --save .. not --save-dev) are:

```
"dependencies": {
  "lzma": "^2.3.0",
  "pako": "^1.0.0",
  "three": "*"
},
```

.. and my scripts cli for hoisting the dependencies into a top level libs/ dir is simply a huge cp:

```
"build-deps": "cp
node_modules/lzma/src/lzma.js
node_modules/lzma/src/lzma_worker.js
node_modules/pako/dist/pako.min.js
node_modules/three/build/three.js
node_modules/three/build/three.min.js
node_modules/three/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js
node_modules/three/examples/js/controls/FlyControls.js
node_modules/three/examples/js/controls/FirstPersonControls.js
node_modules/three/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js
node_modules/three/examples/js/libs/dat.gui.min.js
libs/",
```

This is pretty primitive: I have to find the dependencies in node_modules (not always obvious) and add them to the list by hand. Sure makes me want fewer dependencies! :)

I know that bower is designed for "front end" dependencies (--save in npm speak). But it seems like npm would be perfect for dependencies, and yet it appears I need to be this primitive.

What am I missing here? What do you do?

Answer (score 0):

This is something I wrestled with in my earliest forays into development with Node packages.  I had the exact same idea you had: "I can use npm to pull in whatever I need for my project, great!" and then trying to manage how I reference each of my dependent libraries.  I didn't properly grasp at the time that npm wasn't just there to help me fetch my dependencies, it's also there to help me manage them.

Here's the long & short of it:  you do NOT want to be copying anything out of your node_modules folder to some other, more human-convenient location.  There's a lot of reasons why, but the biggest is that you don't *need* to copy anything out of node_modules -- everything your project needs is right there.

When you're developing in ECMAScript 2015+ you should only ever have to do the following (apologies for the overly-simplistic code):

```js
/* N.B.  These all reside under node_modules, yet I don't 
 *       have to spell out their paths under node_modules: */

import $ from 'jquery';
import _ from 'lodash';
import moment from 'moment';
import NiftyLibrary from 'niftywhatever';

// ... code ...

let $name = $('#name');
let now = moment();

// ... other code ...
```

In other words, your development environment setup should just handle the module resolution for you.  You should never have to specify that the jQuery library you want to use is at "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js".  If you're doing this you should take a minute to figure out why you're doing this -- it's unnecessary, it's a time- and brain-suck and you'd rather be writing your application code than managing your dependencies ... NOT managing the node_modules tree.

You mentioned you're developing with ES6 modules, but not using webpack, gulp, Grunt, rollup or any other build or bundling tool.  Is your project intended to run entirely in Node?  I ask because the last I heard most browsers aren't quite ready to run ES6 modules natively.  So how are your modules getting transpiled to ES5?  Maybe you're approaching this in some novel way I haven't heard of yet, but in my experience a build or bundling tool is necessary.  (Also, it's a heck of a lot of fun.)

I've used Grunt with RequireJS in the past, but am now using webpack 3 with Babel and a few additional loaders (depending on the type of project I'm working on).  I use npm scripts to handle my top-level tasks (running a development server, building a finished distribution package, running tests, etc.), but I let webpack handle all the business of transpiling ES6 into ES5, translating Sass styles, precompiling Vue components, etc.  It's a bit of work to wrap your mind around the webpack approach, but it's well worth the effort.

Maybe webpack doesn't fit your style -- fair enough.  But there are a number of other tools you could use instead.  They all require a little time to get acclimated to their approaches, but they should all be able to take care of module resolution for your dependencies.  Once you get a build environment set up correctly it should cease being a visible part of your development workflow; you'll just reference your dependent libraries by their names, map them to a module-local variable and use them.

Is this helpful?

EDIT:  This is webpack-specific, but there should be similar options available with other bundlers or build tools.

In webpack you can use the copy-webpack-plugin to copy npm-sourced dependencies to a separate folder.  This can be useful within a service worker, for example, where the execution context is a little different.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I don't use any task management tools ... I've converted to npm scripts only as mentioned above. I use Rollup, a minifier etc which npm scripts find easily. I realize webpack will solve several problems. Rollup has a plugin for finding bundle dependencies, I may try it. I don't want to use bower, that's the point of npm use. CDNs may be the best answer. See these for more details: https://medium.com/@backspaces/es6-modules-part-1-migration-strategy-a48de0b7f112
https://medium.com/@backspaces/es6-modules-part-2-libs-wrap-em-up-8715e116d690

Comment: And yes, it IS helpful! Oh, and es6 modules are in all the browsers I use. I think also mobile versions of them. Bleeding edge and all that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is scoping your dependencies (`@frontend/...`) and symlinking the scoped folder to your top-level dir in a post install script (similar to how bower handled the transition to `yarn`: see https://github.com/sheerun/bower-away)

Example:

```
...
"dependencies": {
  "@frontend/jquery": "npm:jquery@~3.4.1",
},
"engines": {
  "npm": ">=6.9.0",
  "node": ">=12.10.0"
},
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "node -e \"try { require('fs').symlinkSync(require('path').resolve('node_modules/@frontend'), 'static/bower', 'junction') } catch (e) { }\""
}
```

Requires NPM >= 6.9 for alias support.

FYI: [aliases break audits](https://npm.community/t/npm-audit-fails-with-aliased-packages/10325)